# How to render a JSF component only if at least two children are rendered (title + item)?

Tags: jsf, el, conditional-rendering

I have a:

```
<h:panelGroup />
  <h:outputText value="title" />
  <h:itemThatSometimesWillShow rendered="sometimes1" />
  <h:itemThatSometimesWillShow rendered="sometimes2" />
  <h:itemThatSometimesWillShow rendered="sometimes3" />
  ...many more
```

And I would like that, if none of the itemThatSometimesWillShow shows, the whole panel (the title, actually) does not show either.

I did try with composite component's `#{cc.childCount} > 1`, but I'm not inside a composite implementation, so looks like it will always return `0`.

Any idea? *(I'm searching for something with js or EL to use in `rendered` attribute of the parent panelGroup)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i would shortly go with this:

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="{bean.isSometimes()}"/>
  <h:outputText value="title" />
  <h:itemThatSometimesWillShow rended="{bean.isSometimes1()}" />
  <h:itemThatSometimesWillShow rended="{bean.isSometimes2()}" />
  <h:itemThatSometimesWillShow rended="{bean.isSometimes3()}" />
```

and in the bean:

```
public boolean isSometimes()
{
    return isSometimes1() || isSometimes2() || isSometimes3();
}
```

Comment: That's what I did for now, thanks! But isn't there a more abstract way?

Answer (score 4):

This is achievable with EL 3.0 stream API. My initial attempt was:

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{component.children.stream().filter(c -> c.rendered).count() gt 1}">
    <h:outputText value="title" />
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{false}">item1</h:panelGroup>
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{false}">item2</h:panelGroup>
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{false}">item3</h:panelGroup>
</h:panelGroup>
```

However, that didn't work quite well. It unexpectedly ran into an infinite loop which ultimately ended with an `OutOfMemoryError`. It appears that `#{component}` EL variable still represents the previous component at the moment the `rendered` attribute is consulted. This is a bit of a chicken-egg issue: the `#{component}` for current component is only injected if its `rendered` attribute evaluates `true`.

Given that, I can see two more options: explicitly find the component by ID as below,

```
<h:panelGroup id="foo" rendered="#{component.findComponent('foo').children.stream().filter(c -> c.rendered).count() gt 1}">
    <h:outputText value="title" />
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{false}">item1</h:panelGroup>
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{false}">item2</h:panelGroup>
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{false}">item3</h:panelGroup>
</h:panelGroup>
```

or let it print some CSS class which in turn does a `display:none;`.

```
<h:panelGroup styleClass="#{component.children.stream().filter(c -> c.rendered).count() gt 1 ? 'show' : 'hide'}">
    <h:outputText value="title" />
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{false}">item1</h:panelGroup>
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{false}">item2</h:panelGroup>
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{false}">item3</h:panelGroup>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: Great! I'm thinking: isnt't there a method like `component.children.size()`? I'll look for it...

Comment: Yup, exactly that, or `#{component.childCount}` for more effectiveness. It only isn't helpful in solving your specific problem as it doesn't consult the children's `rendered` attribute.